# django search not working with more than 2 fields

Tags: django, model, django-queryset

I have a blog app using django with the following models

```
class Category(models.Model):

    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=30,null=False,blank=False)

class Article(models.Model):

    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,null=False,blank=False)
    summary=models.CharField(null=False,blank=False,max_length=400)
    content = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)

class Comment(models.Model):

    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    article=models.ForeignKey(Article,null=False,blank=False)
    visitor_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False,blank=False)
    content=models.TextField(null=False,blank=False)
```

In the admin area, I'm trying to implement a search engine that will allow the admin to search comments using multiple fields.

I'm using the following code :

```
all_queries = None
keywords=''
search_fields = ('visitor_name','content','article__title','article__resume','article__category__title','article__content')
for keyword in keywords.split(' '):
    keyword_query = None
        for field in search_fields:
            each_query = Q(**{field + '__icontains': keyword})
            if not keyword_query:
                keyword_query = each_query
            else:
                keyword_query = keyword_query | each_query
                if not all_queries:
                    all_queries = keyword_query
                else:
                    all_queries = all_queries & keyword_query

comments = Comment.objects.filter(all_queries).distinct().order_by('-date')
```

The problem I am having is with this line :

```
search_fields = ('visitor_name','content','article__title','article__resume','article__category__title','article__content')
```

Somehow I get an empty queryset because I'm searching with 6 fields as I can only search with 2.

For example this line :

```
search_fields = ('visitor_name','content')
```

works very fine because it has exactly two fields for search.

If I add just one field to the array it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a small bug in your logic. You want to AND (`&`) the keyword queries for each keyword, but currently you're AND-ing for each field.

Reduce the level of indentation for the code that builds `all_queries`:

```
all_queries = None
keywords=''
search_fields = ('visitor_name','content','article__title','article__resume','article__category__title','article__content')
for keyword in keywords.split(' '):
    keyword_query = None
    for field in search_fields:
        each_query = Q(**{field + '__icontains': keyword})
        if not keyword_query:
            keyword_query = each_query
        else:
            keyword_query = keyword_query | each_query

    # You only want to do this for each keyword
    if not all_queries:
        all_queries = keyword_query
    else:
        all_queries = all_queries & keyword_query

comments = Comment.objects.filter(all_queries).distinct().order_by('-date')
```